# Do you need to submit a cookie as part of CSRF protection?

Tags: html, security, cookies, csrf

On my website, I put a hidden field in with a randomised value, and I also store that value in the Session at the same time. When the form is submitted, I ensure that the submitted value matches the session value.

Is this sufficient for CSRF protection? Anyone hacking a website to force a user to unknowingly POST to my website will have no idea what the CSRF token is that I generated, and so their attack will fail. The only way to get that token is to do a GET request to the server, and extract the cookie out and post it.

Is that possible? Or in other words, do you have to include a cookie as part of the protection against CSRF? I've not seen it mentioned here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Disclosure_of_Token_in_URL

except for the 'double submitting cookies' part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is sufficient for CSRF protection.  For maximum protection, make sure the hidden, randomized value (the CSRF token) changes every time a request is made.

Cookies are typically recommended because they are easy to use and most web frameworks have a built-in convenient way of utilizing them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think if you use a cookie, you don't need to store anything in the session? Could you create a cookie, put a random value into the cookie and a hidden field, and check they both match? Specifying the cookie as HttpOnly too, to prevent a hacker from reading the contents.

Comment: No unfortunately you will have to store it server side for verification.  If you don't, a malicious server can submit both the "hidden field value" and the "cookie" (basically any made up value that matches) and bypass your controls.  In other words they won't need to get the original token value because they can pass your test without it.  If you try to use only certain values that are valid to test for spoofs, the attacker can just harvest one by using your site like normal and use that value.  It's nasty business :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general this is a good approach.

There is an interaction with session fixation prevention that you'll want to check for. When the user logs in (or changes their session's level of privilege by other means, such as change-user, new-account or implicit login via password-reset), you should be throwing away the old session-stored anti-CSRF token and generating a new one.

This is so that if an attacker managed to get a session-fixation attack against your app, they wouldn't be able to use it to put you into a session, wait for you to login, and then CSRF you. Of course you should be ensuring session fixation doesn't happen anyway, but this is a useful defence in depth measure. (Especially as some potential session fixation routes, like cookie injection from a vulnerable neighbour domain, may be out of your control as developer.)

This is generally simple to do because on privilege level change you should already be invalidating and reissuing the session identifier, to stop session fixation attacks from getting full access to an account. Whilst you're busy doing that, change the CSRF token too.

(There is, however, no need to regenerate the CSRF token for *every* request, as some guides recommend - this will make your application fragile to navigation and multi-tab use.)